Is there a way to disable the "less more" hint in heatmap on flutter?

I'd like to get rid of that less more hint display to look more cleaner but i don't know what to do or where to start.
My Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_heatmap_calendar/flutter_heatmap_calendar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_heatmap_calendar/flutter_heatmap_calendar.dart' as map_heatmap;


class MyHeatMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHeatMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHeatMap> createState() => MyHeatMapState();
}

class MyHeatMapState extends State<MyHeatMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return map_heatmap.HeatMap(
      datasets: {
        DateTime(2024, 1, 6): 3,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 7): 7,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 28): 10,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 9): 13,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 13): 6,
      },
      colorMode: ColorMode.opacity,
      showText: false,
      scrollable: true,
      colorsets: const {
        1: Color.fromARGB(20, 76, 200, 80),
        2: Color.fromARGB(40, 76, 200, 80),
        3: Color.fromARGB(60, 76, 200, 80),
        4: Color.fromARGB(80, 76, 200, 80),
        5: Color.fromARGB(100, 76, 200, 80),
        6: Color.fromARGB(120, 76, 200, 80),
        7: Color.fromARGB(150, 76, 200, 80),
        8: Color.fromARGB(180, 76, 200, 80),
        9: Color.fromARGB(220, 76, 200, 80),
        10: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 200, 80),
      },
      onClick: (value) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value.toString())));
      },
    );
  }
}

I was expecting that it'll look like this if "less more" display gets removed.


pass empty widget to the colorTipHelper: List<Widget?>? property as mentioned at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_heatmap_calendar

You can disable it by using showColorTip: false.
class MyHeatMapState extends State<MyHeatMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return map_heatmap.HeatMap(
      datasets: {
        DateTime(2024, 1, 6): 3,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 7): 7,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 28): 10,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 9): 13,
        DateTime(2024, 1, 13): 6,
      },
      colorMode: map_heatmap.ColorMode.opacity,
      showText: false,
      scrollable: true,
      showColorTip: false,
      colorsets: const {
        1: Color.fromARGB(20, 76, 200, 80),
        2: Color.fromARGB(40, 76, 200, 80),
        3: Color.fromARGB(60, 76, 200, 80),
        4: Color.fromARGB(80, 76, 200, 80),
        5: Color.fromARGB(100, 76, 200, 80),
        6: Color.fromARGB(120, 76, 200, 80),
        7: Color.fromARGB(150, 76, 200, 80),
        8: Color.fromARGB(180, 76, 200, 80),
        9: Color.fromARGB(220, 76, 200, 80),
        10: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 200, 80),
      },
      onClick: (value) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value.toString())));
      },
    );
  }
}

